# how to get equivalent of flex-wrap using -webkit-box?

Tags: css, qt

I am working with modern browsers and need to keep compatibility for an old version of qt that doesn't have flexbox. It has webkit-box though. I can reproduce all the flex features with it except for wrap. I was reading that webkit-box-lines would be the equivalent. I can't get it to work though. Maybe there is something else to it? Would appreciate some input on this as there isn't a whole lot of info on box-flex.  Any other solution would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

All I am doing is this:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
webkit-box-lines: multiple;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: If it is implemented, it would start with a hyphen. i.e. `-webkit-box-lines`.

Comment: I missed it here, but I did add it in the qt browser. It does not wrap elements.